# JSF: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory.

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat, jsf-2

I am using JSF 2.2.4( javax.faces-2.2.4.jar), Tomcat 7.0.52 server and JDK 1.7. I am addding jar to the lib of the application. When I am deploying application to the server it is showing above said exception. I have looked into other related question in *SO* as well as others communities but none of them solved my problem. What is the mistake I am doing ?

Thanks.

Comment: just saying.. have you by any chance forgot to add it in the deployment assembly?

Comment: @anas I have added.. even I have seen deployed assembly